# Some algebraic inequalities with the binomial theorem.

Tags: analysis, binomial-coefficients

I am working on proving the following limits.

> 1), $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$
>
> 2), If $p >0$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {n^{\alpha}\over{(1+p)^n}} =0$

And I am trying to follow the proof but I am stuck on understanding the following inequalities regarding the binomial theorem.

Put $x_n = \sqrt[n]{n} -1$. then $$n = (1+x_n)^n \ge {n(n-1) \over 2}x_n^2 $$

I understand that the right side of the inequality probably comes from $$1 + nx_n + {n \choose 2}x_n^2 + ・・・+x_n^n$$

and taking all the terms after ${n \choose 2}x_n^2$.

But to know this I think that $x_n^k$ has to be greater than $x_n^2$ for $k > 2$, am I right?
Since we can only say that $x_n > 0$, I'm a little puzzled.

For the second one,$$(1+p)^n > {n \choose k}p^k = {n(n-1)・・・(n-k+1) \over {k!}}p^k > {n^kp^k \over {2^k k!}}$$

is supposedly true when $n > 2k$.

I understand the left three expressions, but how does the right side of the inequality work ?

Answer (score 1):

The first confusion is just a misunderstanding. If you have $A=B+C$ with $B,C$ greater than $0$, then no matter what happens to $B,C$'s relationship, $A>B$ is always true.

For the second one all you need to show is $(n-k+1)\ge \frac{n}{2}$ if $n\ge 2k$. But this should be clear to you via some algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's really tough to self teach analysis. But thanks ! Now I can move on to the next theorems.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: since it is true that $\,\sqrt[n] n\ge 1\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ (why?) , we can write

$$\sqrt[n] n=1+c_n\;,\;\;0\le c_n\in \Bbb R\implies $$

$$\implies n=(1+c_n)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkc^k_n\ge\binom n2c_n^2=\frac{n(n-1)}2c_n^2\implies$$

$$\implies 0\le c_n\le\sqrt{\frac2{n-1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

The squeeze theorem then gives

$$c_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies \sqrt[n]n=1+c_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I actually only needed to know why (1+c_n)^n > n(n-1)/2 c_n^2 because I already knew the rest of the proof, but since you put some extra steps inside it actually made sense.